# Force Android orientation to landscape

Tags: android, screen, orientation

As the title suggests, I am having trouble locking the orientation.

I am using the below code:

```
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

This is working ok as far as it loads in landscape and when I rotate the mobile, it stays in landscape.
The problem however, is when the power button is pressed to lock the phone, upon unlocking the app is now forced portrait.
Is there a way to capture the unlock event and force it to goto landscape again or any other method?

Thanks in advance.

Just fixed it myself, if anyone else is experiencing the same issue try the following:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this in the `onCreate()` method, as well as in the `onResume()`, you can also set it in the `onStop()` as well:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: The behaviour is repeating?

Comment: It was yes, until I added that snippet I added to my original post.

Comment: :) I'm glad you figured it out.